# JavaScript onclick multi div change class list add/remove return to back?

Tags: javascript, html

Have multi DIV use Java onclick one of the change DIV class list value, then click other DIV same to change class value, but prior to changed DIV how to return to back class value?

```js
<div id="PART1"class="class1"><a href="" onclick="click1()">TEXT1</a></div>
<div id="PART2"class="class1"><a href="" onclick="click2()">TEXT2</a></div>
<div id="PART3"class="class1"><a href="" onclick="click3()">TEXT3</a></div>

<script>
    var div1=document.getElementByID(PART1);
    var div2=document.getElementByID(PART2);
    var div3=document.getElementByID(PART3);

    function click1(){
        div1.classList.remove("class1");
        div1.classList.add("class2");
    }

    function click2(){
        div2.classList.remove("class1");
        div2.classList.add("class2");
    }

    function click3(){
        div3.classList.remove("class1");
        div3.classList.add("class2");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: is the answer suite with your expect?

Answer (score 0):

You need add quote to id name and change to `getElementById` instead of `getElementByID`

Use `div1.classList.contains("class1"))` to check div has class or not

Also should add `href="#"` to prevent reload page.

```
var div1=document.getElementById('PART1');
var div2=document.getElementById('PART2');
var div3=document.getElementById('PART3');
```

```js
var div1=document.getElementById('PART1');
var div2=document.getElementById('PART2');
var div3=document.getElementById('PART3');

function click1(){
if(div1.classList.contains("class1")){
  div1.classList.remove("class1");
  div1.classList.add("class2");
}else{
div1.classList.remove("class2");
  div1.classList.add("class1");
}

}

function click2(){
if(div2.classList.contains("class1")){
  div2.classList.remove("class1");
  div2.classList.add("class2");
}else{
div2.classList.remove("class2");
  div2.classList.add("class1");
}
}

function click3(){
if(div3.classList.contains("class1")){
  div3.classList.remove("class1");
  div3.classList.add("class2");
}else{
div3.classList.remove("class2");
  div3.classList.add("class1");
}
}
```

```css
.class1{
background-color:red;
}
.class2{
background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="PART1"class="class1"><a href="#" onclick="click1()">TEXT1</a></div>
<div id="PART2"class="class1"><a href="#" onclick="click2()">TEXT2</a></div>
<div id="PART3"class="class1"><a href="#" onclick="click3()">TEXT3</a></div>
```